# laravel ecommerce project - checkout validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Lets say user has added some products when it was available. After some time, my store has decided to remove the product or the product is out of stock. I would like to add functionality to delete the cart items which are 1) no longer available or 2) out of stock when user enters the checkout page. This would have been easier if i had just single products without options in my website. There are two types of products = 1) product with color options and 2) product without any options

Below is my attempt to add this functionality

```
 public function render()
{
    $this->fullname = auth()->user()->name;
    $this->email = auth()->user()->email;

    $this->phone = auth()->user()->userDetail->phone;
    $this->pincode = auth()->user()->userDetail->pincode;
    $this->address = auth()->user()->userDetail->address;
    $this->secondAddress = auth()->user()->userDetail->address2;
    $this->thirdAddress = auth()->user()->userDetail->address3;

    $this->totalProductAmount = $this->totalProductAmount();

    $cartItems = Cart::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem)
    {
        if ($cartItem->product_color_id != NULL) {

            if (!ProductColor::where('product_id', $cartItem->product_id)
                                ->where('color_id', $cartItem->product_color_id)
                                ->where('quantity','>', $cartItem->quantity)->exists())
            {
                $removeCart =  Cart::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                                    ->where('product_id', $cartItem->product_id)
                                    ->where('product_color_id', $cartItem->product_color_id)
                                    ->first();
                $removeCart->delete();
            }

        } else {

            if (!Product::where('id', $cartItem->product_id)->where('quantity','>', $cartItem->quantity)->exists())
            {
                $removeCart = Cart::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                                    ->where('product_id', $cartItem->product_id)
                                    ->first();
                $removeCart->delete();
            }
        }
    }

    return view('livewire.frontend.checkout.checkout-show', [
        'totalProductAmount' =>  $this->totalProductAmount
    ]);
}
```

However this code just deletes all of the cart items even though some products were available or were in-stock.

Cart model

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductColor;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Cart extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'carts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'product_id',
        'product_color_id',
        'quantity'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the Cart
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function product(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

    public function productColors(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductColor::class, 'product_color_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you re-grabbing the item? You should just be able to do `$cartItem->delete()`

Comment: $cartItem->delete() in what conditions? That is what i want to know how to structure it

Comment: Good question. You might want to add some logging to see what might be happening. Add something like `Log::info("Does product have more than $cartItem->quantity?" . ProductColor::where('product_id', $cartItem->product_id)->where('color_id', $cartItem->product_color_id)->first()?->quantity);` -- You may have to tweak this for your use case. I'd also suggest checking where quantity is `>=`, otherwise exact quantities will be missed.